# UIActivityViewController Facebook sharing URL + IMAGE and URL + TEXT not working

Tags: swift4, ios11, uiactivityviewcontroller

Please don't mark duplicate already seen [iOS11: UIActivityViewController not successfully sharing UIImage to 3rd party apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840674/ios11-uiactivityviewcontroller-not-successfully-sharing-uiimage-to-3rd-party-ap)

So I am trying to share Image + URL with `UIActivityViewController` .
However when tap on facebook it only show `URL`, Image is not showingup

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func btnShareTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let image = self.imgBackground.image, let jpgImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
        let shareItems:Array = [jpgImage,URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")] as [Any]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo]
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove `URL` then I can able to share image,

Only URL Visible  for sharing

[image: Only URL Visible not image]

Is there any workaround to share Image with URL or any text ?

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: @balkaransingh It is not possible :(

Answer (score 2):

it's impossible to share images and URL at the same time currently